# What do you call the left hand side variables in a regression/classification?

Tags: regression, classification, terminology

If I have a regression or classification problem

```
y ~ x1 + x2 + ... + xn
```

I might call the `xi` the *regressors* or the *predictors*. But what do you call `y`?

The terms *regressand* and *predictand* are clunky, don't seem particularly standard, and have the disadvantage that they're very similar to the words for the right-hand-side variables (I'm going to be using these terms in type declarations and documentation for a program, so minimizing the potential for confusion is a priority).

Also, using *regressor* and *regressand* is inappropriate when you have a classification problem, rather than a regression.

Is there a commonly used term?

Comment: I think the "response" or "outcome" variable are commonly used terms.

Comment: What if you are using regression to do classification?

Comment: 'outcome' also seems fine for classification.  Or try 'class' or 'category'.  If you're really fitting regression models for classification purposes you should probably stop, and use a proper model instead ;-)

Comment: In regression it is also called the dependent variable or DV and the Xs are called the independent variables or IVs.  However the independent variables do not have to be and usually are not statistical independent.

Comment: @ConjugatePrior Is logistic regression considered a regression method?  Since glm is a generalization of the linear model, cannot glm be considered regression too?

Comment: @ConjugatePrior I can think of a few cases where you'd want to fit a regression model for classification - for example, logistic regression (if you want to classify a binary variable).

Comment: @jkd.  Folks, this just is a terminology issue.  I was using regression in the original 'regression to mean' sense (and also the machine learning sense, see e.g. Bishop 2006) as a contrast to 'classification'. I agree GLMs are certainly regressions in the wider sense.  However, some people really do use linear regression to perform classification, which now looks rather old-fashioned.  *They* were the target of that offhand remark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "response" or "outcome" variables are commonly used terms.

Comment: Some fields talk of "criterion" variables.